# Why is the restriction of this map zero?

Tags: functional-analysis

I have to show that the following holds for a Banach space $E$ and a subspace $F\subseteq E$:
$$\forall f\in E'\colon f\vert_F=0 \text{ then }f=0\implies F \text{ is dense}.$$

The proof starts as follows. Suppose $F$ is not dense. Then $\{x_0\}\cap \overline{F}=\emptyset$ for some $x_0\in E$ and Hahn-Banach gives an $f\in E'$ and $\alpha, \beta\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\forall x\in F\colon f(x)<\alpha<\beta<f(x_0).$$
Apparently, we now have that $f\vert_F=0$, such that we get a contradiction and we are done. I must be missing something small, because I don't see why $f\vert_F=0$. Can you give me the reason?

Comment: $F$ is a linear subspace of $E$, so $f(F)$ is a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}$. And since it's not all of $\mathbb{R}$ …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a step missing. Say, you have found continuous $f$ with $f(x)<\alpha<\beta<f(x_0)$ for all $x\in F$. Let $h\colon \Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be given as $h(x)=\max\{0,x-\alpha\}$. Then $h$ is continuous, hence $g:=h\circ f$ is a continuous function and for *this* function we have $g|_F=0$. By assumption, it follows that $g=0$, in particular $g(x_0)=0$. On the other hand $g(x_0)>\beta-\alpha>0$, contradiction.